# Calendly : generation of access code on server side (without redirection)

Tags: javascript, typescript, passport.js, nestjs, calendly

As showcased on the calendly demo app [link](https://github.com/calendly/buzzwordcrm.git) is there any way create access token and refresh token on server side only, because as per their [Documentation](https://calendly.stoplight.io/) it is not listed anywhere.

I want to achieve something similar.

demo app code:

```
const OAuth2Strategy = require('passport-oauth2').Strategy;

const strategy = new OAuth2Strategy(
    {
        authorizationURL: CALENDLY_AUTH_BASE_URL + '/oauth/authorize',
        tokenURL: CALENDLY_AUTH_BASE_URL + '/oauth/token',
        clientID: CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: CLIENT_SECRET,
        callbackURL: REDIRECT_URI
    },
    async (accessToken, refreshToken, _profile, cb) => {
        const calendlyService = new CalendlyService(accessToken, refreshToken);
        const userInfo = await calendlyService.getUserInfo();

        try {
            const result = await User.findOrCreate({
                accessToken,
                refreshToken,
                calendlyUid: userInfo.resource.uri
            });
            cb(null, { id: result.id });
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e);
            cb();
        }
    }
);
```

My implementation:

```
const OAuth2Strategy = require('passport-oauth2').Strategy;

const strategy = new OAuth2Strategy(
      {
        authorizationURL: CALENDLY_AUTH_BASE_URL + '/oauth/authorize',
        tokenURL: CALENDLY_AUTH_BASE_URL + '/oauth/token',
        clientID: CLIENT_ID ,
        clientSecret: CLIENT_SECRET,
        callbackURL: REDIRECT_URI,
      },
      async (accessToken, refreshToken, _profile, cb) => {
        // console.log(IArguments)
        console.log('async func called');
        console.log(accessToken, refreshToken);

        try {
          cb(null,this.getRequestConfiguration(accessToken, refreshToken));
        } catch (e) {
          console.error(e);
          cb();
        }
      }
    );
```

In the response I am getting undefined for accessToken, refreshToken.